# IntelliJ idea deeplearning4j debugger has discrepancy in data

Tags: intellij-idea, deeplearning4j

I work with deeplearning4j and created INDArray of quite big size. Into that array I write some values. If I try to see those values in debugger, initially I see zeros, and only for data at FloatBuffer I see entered values. See the screenshot.

[image: INDArray with missing values]

If to debug the code of XorExample in deeplearning4j such behavior I didn't notice:
[image: INDArray with displayed values]

Is there any way to always show or always hide values that sit inside of INDArray without shoving zeros? Or it is some kind of bug inside of idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default debugger evaluates and shows toString() defined in the NDArray class (or BaseNDArray in your case). You can replace it with your custom renderer for this type. The easiest way is to right click on a variable -> View as -> Create...
Or go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java Type Renderers.
Then put your requred expression into "When rendering a node" expression.